# OpenCV cvDrawContours vs drawContours

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012, contour

I am new to using OpenCV on Visual Studio, and I have recently reinstalled my VS2012 to get it to work using OpenCV 2.4.2.

I am trying to calculate the area of region specified by mouse-clicking the vertices and pushing them to CvSeq*, to use with contourArea() function.

I am currently trying to parse in an empty CvSeq* as the last parameter of my custom mouse callback function so that I can add the CvPoint formed of x and y coordinates. However, whenever I try to access the CvSeq* contour afterwards, I get an error. So in the following snippet of the code:

```
void CallBackFunc(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* userdata)
{

    CvSeq* contour = (CvSeq*)userdata;
    CvPoint cur;
     if  ( event == EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN )
     {
          cout << "Left button of the mouse is clicked - position (" << x << ", " << y << ") saved as point" << endl;
          // save x,y as a contour point
          cur = cvPoint(x,y);
          cvSeqPush(contour, &cur);
...
```

I get the correct cout messages, but get an error like this when trying to draw contour using that CvSeq* :
Unhandled exception at at 0x75E3812F in opencvtest.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x001FF990.

What is the problem here? Would I be better off trying to use Vector> instead of CvSeq?

Comment: Just curious, if you're just starting with OpenCV why not start with the latest version (2.4.9) instead of a very old version (2.4.2)?

Comment: had some installation issues and went back to a version where there was a documented installation guide online

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- cvDrawContours() is from the old, deprecated c-api, you should *not* use it, or any of those old cv* functions.
- drawContours is from the current c++ api, use it with cv::Mat, functions from the cv:: namespace.

---

also, stop worrying about CvSeq* or IplImage*. if you see any code that contains arcane stuff like that, - move on.

"Would I be better off trying to use `vector<vector<Point>>` instead of CvSeq?" - yes.

---

also, when in doubt, have a look at the [samples](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/2.4/samples) and the [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/)

Comment: Thanks a lot @berak !! 
If my Visual Studio auto complete seems to be showing cvDrawContours() and not the drawContours(), does that mean there is something wrong with my settings?

Comment: that probably means, that you included the c-api headers instead of the c++ ones. please include "opencv2/core/core.hpp", "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp", etc.

Comment: Hmm strange... I just checked, and those are the exact ones I have included... is this a version issue perhaps? I'm on OpenCV2.4.2, having reverted back from the most recent version to try to get it to work

Comment: ok, "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp" to be exact. and make sure, you did not include older headers, like cv.h *before*

Comment: Ah works now, thanks a lot! Is there an easy way to search for which functions are included in which header files?

Comment: in vs that should be: right click on it, -> go to definition

Comment: Oh I meant if there was a website where I can check which of the OpenCV library functions are included in which header files so I can include the correct ones..? My googling ability failed me with drawContours(), as you could probably tell...